# Liquibase yaml inserts

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

We are using a stack on SpringBoot, Hibernate and Liquibase. I have a sql file with 24000 inserts. When I converted it into yaml (for versioning purposes), I got a huge yaml file which I split into 16 yamls. Insertion using the master file using the liquibase command line option is pretty quick. But with Spring and Hibernate, it gets stuck. Upto 5 files is fine. Anything more than this dosn't work.
I tried with 4 files each from the 16 files and it works too. So it is not an issue with any malformed yaml files. I also tried with the following properties in my application.yml.

```
 spring:
      datasource:
        hikari:
          maximum-pool-size: 100


     properties:
          hibernate:
            jdbc:
              batch_size: 200

        Basically, it gets stuck at the changelog lock. This is what the log shows:

        2019-10-17 18:10:26.375  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
        2019-10-17 18:10:26.387  WARN 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
        2019-10-17 18:10:26.927  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
        2019-10-17 18:10:27.760  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pbr.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
        2019-10-17 18:10:27.794  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pbr.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
        2019-10-17 18:10:27.804  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT `LOCKED` FROM pbr.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1
        2019-10-17 18:10:27.812  INFO 1 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Waiting for changelog lock....
        2019-10-17 18:10:37.816  INFO 1 --- [           main] liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor      : SELECT `LOCKED` FROM pbr.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1
        2019-10-17 18:10:37.821  INFO 1 --- [           main] l.lockservice.StandardLockService        : Waiting for changelog lock..
```

It did not work. Please help me.

The inserts are  like this:
databaseChangeLog:
- changeSet:
    id: 15706644546-4
    author: pbr-admin
    changes:
    - insert:
        columns:
        - column:
            name: model_id
            value: xxxxx
        - column:
            name: category_id
            value: ALL_TRANSACTIONS
        - column:
            name: afpr_indexed
            valueBoolean: false
        - column:
            name: score
            valueNumeric: xxx

The changelog is liquibase specific.

Comment: can you print an example of your insert statement. are you using locks ? or it's liquibase native code

Comment: you can consider https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase-nochangeloglock as well, which completely disables the lock support

Comment: It seems like something is trying to do four operations in parallel, and each is getting the databasechangeloglock and then preventing the others from continuing - classic deadlock. If you could limit it to a single thread you'd probably be fine. Not sure where that 4 parallel threads is coming from though - spring boot or hibernate.